# Unity OnMouseUp and OnCollisionEnter at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)` and `void OnMouseUp()`, but I want it to be so that if I release my mouse, then collision should be checked. So I would like a function in another function.

```
void OnMouseUp()
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {

    }
}
```

Ofcourse it's not possible this way, so how should I do this else?

Comment: Why not just call `OnCollisionEnter` inside `OnMouseUp`

Comment: @Henkan you shouldn't call event triggers manually. It's bad practice at best, and I don't even know if it will compile.

Comment: @Henkan Because OnCollisionEnter requires a second collider to be present within the bounds of the collider expected to trigger that event - it's an interaction between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OnCollisionEnter and OnMouseUp are called once in a frame and never again until the you repeat the event or collision happens again. You need a boolean flag to guarantee that you won't miss either `OnMouseUp` or `OnCollisionEnter` because this happens very fast.

```
bool collided = false;

void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (collided)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collding while mouse is up");
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    collided = true;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    collided = false;
}
```

Or even without `OnMouseUp`

```
bool collided = false;

void Update()
{
    if ((Input.GetMouseButton(0)) && collided)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collding while mouse is up");
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    collided = true;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    collided = false;
}
```

Comment: `OnMouseUp` and `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` don't function the same way though, right? It was my understanding that the former was for when the mouse was positioned over the object and the second is irrespective of its position. Of course, I'm probably mistaken though.

Comment: They actually do. The only difference is that one is a callback function and the other one is just polling. Each one will be called **once** only.

Comment: Hmm, must be a different `On...()` that I'm thinking of then.

Comment: Np. You should give both a try sometimes and see how they both work

Comment: @TJWolschon You may be thinking of `OnMouseOver`

Answer (score 4):

You wording is a little ambiguous. When you say "release my mouse" I'm assuming you mean "no longer holding left click", if that's wrong let me know.

All you have to do is, in `OnCollisionStay()` just check if the mouse button is not being held down

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision other)
{
    //check if left mouse is not being held down
    if(!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        //write your collision code here
    }
}
```

EDIT: modified so that it works on more than just the first frame of collision entry/ mouse release.

I like @Programmer's answer better, and generally I would use that method for collisions, but I'll leave this up in case someone finds it useful some day.

Comment: @Draco18s True! Maybe it'd be better with `OnCollisionStay`?

Comment: @Draco18s I've edited it slightly, I think this version is better now. I actually meant to do `GetMouseButton` from the get-go, but had a bit of a brain-fart.

Comment: To handle a custom collision system like this it would be better to create a bool that says you are colliding, setting that bool when you begin to collide, and unsetting it when you are no longer collider `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` using your update then to check if you are still colliding, and you are not holding the mouse button, handle your collision there.

Comment: @Eddge agreed, generally that's how I do it in my own projects but was unsure if the OP needed it a certain way, so I tried to stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate child object for your collider and enable then disable that object within the `OnMouseUp` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool mouseReleased = false;
void OnMouseDown() => mouseReleased = false;
void OnMouseUp() => mouseReleased = true;
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    if(mouseReleased)
    {
        mouseReleased = false;
        // Do something
    }
}
```